# When do we need to use gcc/g++ to generate Map files? "-g" is enough for debug?

Tags: linux, debugging, dictionary, gcc, gdb

If we want to use gdb to debug a release version executable, we make sure we compile using -g and then use objcopy to trim the debug information. This debug information can be used to locate source file lines when going through source files.

But when/why do we also need to generate Map files, any requirement or ability of gdb relies on Map files?

Thanks.

Comment: _use objcopy to trim the debug information_ - what does that do?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin He probably means `strip -g` and separate debuginfo files: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html

Comment: @employedrussian the abilities were only recently added to strip. With objcopy you can extract the debug section to a separate file, remove it from the source executable and then add a section that tells things like gdb that the filename to look at for symbols.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But when/why do we also need to generate Map files, any requirement or ability of gdb relies on Map files?

Assuming you are talking about the linker `-M` (synonym to `--print-map`) and `-Map` options, these are *purely* debugging aids intended to tell you what code/data is being pulled into your binary (and why).

GDB does not need or use this output (and the output is not easily parseable, i.e. intended for human consumption only).

**Update:**

> when and how do we use this map file?

As I said before, the file answers questions like:

- which object or library did the given function come from?
- how much space did it consume in `.text` or `.data` section?
- why did this particular object file get selected into the link from an archive library (i.e. which unresolved symbol caused this object file to be linked in)?

You use the map file when you have one of the above questions. If you don't have such questions, then you don't have any need for the map file.

As for "how" -- just read it with your favorite editor or pager. If you have a *specific* question on how to interpret particular lines there, *do* ask a separate *specific* question.

Comment: So when and how do we use this map file? I don't find clues from google. Thanks!